# Netty Websocket issue on CEntOS 6

Tags: javascript, websocket, netty

I'd netty running on my dev machine which runs Windows 7. Now, When I migrate my app to a CEntOS 6 server, all websocket communications do not work. I thought that it is because of iptables restrictions. So, I added entries for the ports used to the iptable.

My interface binding information is 0.0.0.0:port, and the URL I use in my client code to access the websocket is ws://SERVER_IP:port/. I've googled for sometime now in vain. Any assistance will be appreciated. My client uses JavaScript.

**UPDATE:**
When I run netstat -nlp, I see `:::port_number` for local address and `:::*` for the foreign address. I'm thinking that this should be `0.0.0.0:port_number` for the local address and `0.0.0.0:*` for the foreign address. May be I'm missing something in my configuration.

**UPDATE:** 
After a painstaking troubleshooting process, I found out the root of my problem was my network security configuration. After resolving this, everything now works fine.

Comment: Is the problem resolved when you stop the ip tables service?

Comment: No. I've tried that. Stopping iptables doesn't solve it.

Comment: It may be stating the obvious, but on many Linux distributions binding to port 80 requires root permissions.

Comment: I'm not using port 80. I'm using port 8080. I've established that the port is open and can accept connections; it can even server static resources using http, but websockets does not work.